# What is the maximum PE file header size?

Tags: portable-executable

Does someone know the maximum PE **file header** size? I can find information on the maximum PE file size only.

Answer (score 1):

PE header is usually about 500 bytes (might be slightly longer if you define a lot of sections, but you would heve real trouble going over 1024, i guess